# Angular.JS - only allow up to a certain number value in an input number field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand a way with angular where I can only let the user enter a number that isn't more than 24 or in my other input 60 to represent hours and minutes.

```
            <input type="number"
                   placeholder="HH"
                   ng-minlength="2"
                   ng-maxlength="2"
                   required
                   ng-model="session.timeHH">

            <input type="number"
                   placeholder="mm"
                   ng-minlength="2"
                   required
                   ng-maxlength="2"
                   ng-model="session.timeMM">
```

This is my HTML at the moment.

The user can enter in the hours input a number like 99 which is obviously going to be wrong. I'm looking for a way to validate or prevent the user before submit to only be able to enter numbers up to 24 for hours and 59 for minutes.

Or even on the click of the submit button would be sufficient.

Comment: Well, if it's enough to just validate, you could use `min` and `max` attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not angular, but why not use the HTML attributes?  Angular is hip to these and you can check the $valid property of the form to make sure the constraints are satisfied.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="24" step="1">
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what the step attribute does please?

Comment: @MaxLynn It makes sure that everytime a user clicks on + or - it will increase or decrease with 1

Comment: @MaxLynn Setting `step=1` indicates that you want an integer.  You'd use `step=.01` for currency.  It's the interval between valid values.  And also what Mikey said.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this

Answer (score 2):

How about just HTML5 since you're already using `type="number"`:

```
<input type="number" name="hours" min="1" max="24">
```

Be sure to also validate input on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict numbers use a dropdown, otherwise you'll have to use native min and max attributes with validation.

Comment: That's a poor user experience IMO.

Comment: @Casey its better than letting users input false data and having to re-enter it when the form is submitted and validation fails

Comment: He's using angular; there's no reason the user can't have that validation as he enters or blurs the field.  You don't have to wait for a submit.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of the type properties to the inputs as time, this will open a time selector on modern browsers and mobiles

https://plnkr.co/edit/TAwugxjQHcMtJONQJgWA?p=preview

```
         <input type="time"
               placeholder="HH:MM"
               required
               ng-model="session.timeHH">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some angular **mask** lib that provides masking features.

The ones you could use are, for example, `angular-input-masks`, `ui-mask` or `ngMask`.

Comment: Not sure I can justify a lib for this

Comment: Yes, these exist, but that's inappropriate for this problem.

Comment: Indeed. That's just an option.